# Error getting the version of the native layer: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path

Tags: java, servlets, jco

In my Java Web application, trying to connect SAP Server. This error is generated:

> Error getting the version of the native layer: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path

I have placed the `sapjco3.dll` and `sapjco3.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib/` and also configured in the Java Build Path.

I have also set the Path in servlet as

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/WEB-INF/lib");
```

But also error existing.

Comment: Can this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643905/exception-while-connecting-sap-through-java

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your approach

1. It is not recommended to change `java.library.path` programmatically, since the property is cached at the JVM start. See [Setting "java.library.path" programmatically](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/) for more details.
2. You are overwriting `java.library.path` instead of adding your directory at the end. It's very likely your application server needs some native libraries of its own.
3. `/WEB-INF/lib` is a relative path which your JVM is not going to find as the JVM root directory is different from your app root directory (not to mention if you are deploying a WAR file)

In general, you should configure your SAP JCo as a server library, not an application library. The exact procedure depends of your application server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows like me you can put the **sapjco3.dll** anywhere you want in the file system (except for the Windows **system32** and **sysWOW64** directories, as stated in the sapjco3 documentation) and then add the path to it to your **Path** system variable:

[image: sapjco3.dll in Path system variable]

On Linux you add the path to the **libsapjco3.so** file to the environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

If you are on JBoss and need to get sapjco3.jar into you project see my answer over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901220/1592796