# Glassfish 4.0 and SAP JCo3

Tags: java, glassfish, connector, jco

Searching thoroughly the internet and trying everything I found I came to a dead end.

There are no instructions that I can find to help me install SAP java connector (SAP JCo3) to Glassfish Server 4.0.

As I understand (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/820-7202/ggymv/index.html) SAP JCo has to be implemented through Connector Connection Pools. I tried to copy `sapjco3.jar`, `sapjco3.dll` and `sapjco3.pdb` to every possible location with no luck.

My server runs windows 2003. If you have done it, please help me!

Thank you,

Gilop

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided does not contain any information about the required dll file, which is the native library for JCo 3 (on linux the file is named libsapjco3.so for example).

Take a look inside the javadoc folder of the sapjco3 archive you got from SAP, there is a file named **intro.html** which contains instructions on how to install JCo 3 on many operating systems (click on the **Installation** link at the top of the page).

Quote from intro.html in the sapjco3-NTAMD64-3.0.10 archive:

> To install JCo for Windows unzip the appropriate distribution package into an arbitrary directory {sapjco3-install-path}.
>
> Note: Do not copy the sapjco3.dll neither into the {windows-dir}\system32 nor into the {windows-dir}\SysWOW64 directory. This will break the operability of other JCo versions that are already installed on the same system. Furthermore you would risk that the current installation also would not work anymore, if the sapjco3.dll gets replaced in the respective Windows system directory in the future.
>
> Then add {sapjco3-install-path} to the PATH environment variable.
> Finally, add {sapjco3-install-path}\sapjco3.jar to your CLASSPATH environment variable.

I have followed the above instructions and got it working on Windows 7 64 bit and JBoss EAP 6.1.

See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901789/1592796) for a screenshot of the modified PATH environment variable.

Comment: I did it (in fact it was the first thing I did). But didn't success to have sapjco operable in Glassfish.

Comment: Ok, this is bad, is there an error message you can provide or something like that?

Comment: No, it is just impossible to get it working. SAPjco is invisible from Glassfish. That's why I asked for install instructions to follow. At least I could get an error message.

Comment: I have GF4 and SAPJco 3 working together in Windows environment and also in Linux environment. In both cases I put the .dll/.so in the domains/domain1/bin folder. Everything works fine.
The connection data I put in a file called sapconnection.props located in domains/domain1/config folder. Of course you have to restart the server to get the .dll/.so loaded.
Hope that helps.