# JCo problem with javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, jco

when I test the JCo connection to SAP system, I got following error

> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sap.conn.rfc.driver.CpicDriver.nativeSAP_CMINIT3([BLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)I
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
>       org.apache.jsp.notif_005fget_005fdetail_jsp._jspService(notif_005fget_005fdetail_jsp.java:99)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
> ```

I already put `sapjco3.dll` and `sapjco3.jar` into lib, I have no idea with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure the native JCo library is located in a folder which is part of the java.library.path.

2) Make sure you use the correct native JCo library for your system architecture (e.g. Linux 64bit on x86) and the sapjco3.jar from the same JCo distribution.

See also here: [Exception while connecting SAP through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643905/exception-while-connecting-sap-through-java/13777308#13777308)